# Connect LINQPad to Remote Server

Tags: sql-server, remote-access, linqpad

I have followed [this tutorial](http://bit.ly/1CNPxss) to enable Remote Access on my Virtual Dedicated Server, I restarted SQL Service on remote server as well.

When I attempt to connect to the remote sql server I get the following error:

[image: linqpad connection error]

In the connection dialog below, I input my details in the format show:

[image: connection dialog]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the firewall step (in tutorial) I had chosen `Domain`, but should have chosen `Public` because my home PC is not on the same Domain as my server. That fixed it.